# In ModernCV, how to define a command in the cls style file to allow lines with right-aligned word.

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

I am using [ModernCV](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) for my CV. I want to achieve something like the following example (please note that the address "`align2@rightMargin.com`" is aligned to the right margin):

[image: Example]

Please note the last word is not necessarily an email address but any other word. In the example above what I used is the `\hspace` command, so I have to estimate the `hspace` manually everytime I change length of the sentence. I notice `\raggedleft` may be the right command, but I don't know how to make a command like `\cvline` in the ModernCV `cls` file to achieve the above example. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @user3690 Try using `\hfill` rather than `\hspace`.

Comment: @user3690: Welcome to tex.sx. You can use the icons on top of the edit window to include hyperlinks or use `[text](URL)` to do it. Please use `\`` to mark your macro names and other inline code. I included the image for you. You can do this by yourself once you got 10rep points.

Comment: @Martin: thanks for including the image for me.

Comment: @Yiannis: \hfill works exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\hfill` rather than `\hspace` and it should work.