# moderncv - How do I put the date column on the right rather than on the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

The career advisor at my university suggests putting the title of the position on the left, and dates on the right side of the resume. 
I'm wondering how to I do that in `moderncv` themes?

*Edit: My apologies for not closing this question. I totally forgot it. 
The comment by xavier is the answer i was looking for but I'll accept the post as the correct answer for the credit.*

Comment: But, if I understand your request, the space for the position might be not large enough. What to do in such cases?

Comment: Which style are you using? If you're using the [`classic`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_classic_green.pdf) or [`casual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_casual_orange.pdf) style, you would need to redefine `\cventry` (though the result might be slightly weird if I correctly picture what your career advisor means). The `oldstyle` or `banking` style already put dates on the right, with the `banking` style being close to the default MBA template requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-align dates by doing something like this:

```
Store Clerk \hfill 2008-2012
```

It might be wiser to create your own commands for positions and dates, such that you can format them differently later without having to retype anything.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
\newcommand{\rdate}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\position}{\par\noindent\hspace*{0pt}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\details}{\par\noindent\hspace*{30pt}\ignorespaces}
```

You could then write `\position{Store Clerk}`followed by `\hfill`followed by `\rdate{Aug 2008-Sep 2012}`

Why would you consider putting the dates or other information into custom environments? You might realize later that some of your lines are too long. Perhaps the left-aligned information overlaps the date. This would be no problem, because you could just make the text smaller, for example `\newcommand{\details}[1]{\par\noindent\hspace*{30pt}\ignorespaces{\tiny #1}`

---

Two Youtube Videos might help you (although they use the article class)

- [CV Part One](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fJ6ZmMkOn8)
- [CV Part Two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ2EYFM3duk)

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question at all – it is about `moderncv`.

Comment: I disagree. `moderncv`is irrelevant. It could just as well be another class. See a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/in-moderncv-how-to-define-a-command-in-the-cls-style-file-to-allow-lines-with-r Considering that no one has answered this question after a months time, I figured it would be prudent to provide one.